# How to find $P(X=1 ∧ Z=2)$ where $P(X=1)$ and $P(Z=2)$ is given?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

$P(X=0) = 1/4$, $P(X= 1) = 1/4$, $P(X=2)= 1/2$

$P(Y=0)= 1/2$, $P(Y= 1) = 1/3$, $P(Y= 2) = 1/6$

It is given X and Y is independent and $Z$ is defined by $XY$

So $P(Z=0) = 5/8$, $P(Z=1) = 1/12$, $P(Z=2) = 5/24$, $P(Z=4) = 1/12$

**(Q1)** Find **$P(X=1 ∧ Z=2)$**

I did it by multiplying $P(X=1)$ into $P(Z=2)$, but i think that is wrong. What is the correct way?

**(Q2)** Using your answers to **Q(1)** find **$P(X=1|Z=2)$**

I did  **$[P(X=1)∩P(Z=2)]/P(Z=2)$** = $1/4$

**(Q3)** Using your answers to **Q(1)** show that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent random variables.

So independent if $P(X=1 ∩ Z=2)= P(X=1)*P(Z=2)$ But it depends on the answer to 1) which I am not sure about. Apart from he calculations it obvious that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent as $Z= XY$

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @drhab from the probabilities being given for P(Z) it would appear that X and Y are independent.

Comment: @user137481 I expect independence, yes. But that must be mentioned in the question. If it lacks then this question misses context and is not okay.

Comment: SAR, for Q1, notice that $P(X=1, Z=2) = P(X=1, Y=2)$. However to proceed further, you need to provide the context as to whether X and Y are independent as drhab has requested.

Comment: @drhab Actually the data implies the independence of (X,Y) hence, mathematically, the question is "okay".

Comment: @drhab Yes X and Y are independent

Comment: @SAR Can you prove that they are?

Comment: @SAR If $X$ and $Y$ are stated to be independent, mention that in the question.

Comment: @Did "So $P(Z=0)=\frac58\dots$" etc. is (or sounds like) a conclusion. I missed the data on which this conclusion is based. The question is now edited and okay.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: Find $P(X=1 \wedge Z=2)$.

We know that $P(X = 1) = 1/4$. If $X = 1$ and $Z = XY = 2$, then $Y = 2$. Thus, 
\begin{align*}
P(X=1 \wedge Z=2) &= P(X = 1 \wedge Y = 2) \\
&= P(X = 1)P(Y = 2) && \text{(Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent)}\\
&= \frac14\frac16 \\
&= \frac{1}{24}
\end{align*}

(Thanks to user137481 for pointing out that $P(X=1, Z=2) = P(X=1, Y=2)$).

> Q2: Using the answer to Q1, find $P(X = 1 \mid Z = 2)$.

Using the definition of conditional probability, we have 
\begin{align*}
P(X = 1 \mid Z = 2) &= \frac{P(X=1 \wedge Z=2)}{P(Z = 2)} \\
&= \frac{1/24}{5/24} \\
&= \frac{1}{5}
\end{align*}

> Q3: Using the answer to Q1, show that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent.

$X$ and $Z$ are independent iff $P(X = x)P(Z = z) = P(X = x \wedge Z = z)$ for all possible values $x, z$ of $X$ and $Z$. Set $x = 1$ and $z = 2$. From your work, we have $P(X = 1)P(Z = 2) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{24} = \frac{5}{96}$. However, from Q1, we have $P(X = x \wedge Z = z) = \frac{1}{24} \neq \frac{5}{96}$. The definition of independence fails to hold, thus $X$ and $Z$ are not independent.